# Join two tables based on a nested field in bigquery

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

i want to join two tables "mapping_physical_countries" and "countries" based on 'iso_country_code' which is a nested field with the 'country_alpha3_id' from countries. The idea is to add a new column to the "mapping_physical_countries"  that contains the countries label for each element in iso_country_code (it will be also a nested field). My query is not working because of this error :

```
No matching signature for operator = for argument types: ARRAY<STRING>, STRING. Supported signature: ANY = ANY
```

This is the "mapping_physical_countries" table :

[image]

An extract of "countries" table:

[image]

Comment: Can you give us the structure and schema of `countries` table please ?

Comment: Additionally, can you also give us the query that you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope it can help.

I propose you a query to solve your issue :

```sql
select 
  mapping_countries.multidivision_cluster,
  country_code as iso_country_code,
  countries.country_alpha3_id
from `project.dataset.mapping_physical_countries`  mapping_countries,
unnest(mapping_countries.iso_country_code) as country_code
inner join `project.dataset.countries` countries on country_code = countries.country_alpha3_id
```

I used `unnest` on `iso_country_code` array.